# problem trying to use hilt in my app: dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

I've been trying to add Hilt in my app but I run into this issue when building:

Execution failed for task ':app:hiltJavaCompilePreprod'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.XTypeElement.getAnnotation(com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName)" because the return value of "dagger.spi.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.XProcessingEnv.findTypeElement(com.squareup.javapoet.TypeName)" is null

I am using jetbrains runtime 17.
Part of my root gradle:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.0.300'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48'
}

//hilt
hiltCompiler: 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48',
hiltKapt: 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48'
```

part of my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'




compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

implementation dmaDependencies.hiltCompiler
kapt dmaDependencies.hiltKapt
```

Could not find any solutions so far, help apprectiated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Dagger issue, requires a dependency to be added,
as explained here
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4241